# FFMPEG: Convert while file is being uploaded (an incomplete file)

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion, upload

I am designing a media upload function using HTML5. My design looks like this at the moment:

- User selects a file for upload
- FileApi (JS) reads this file chunk by chunk and uploads it to the server via `XHR`
- The newly uploaded file chunk is then appended to what will be the full file on the server

It is at this point that I want to start converting what is already there into a web-compatible format, e.g. `mp4` video, etc., until the full file has been uploaded and the conversion can finish.
Note that I can competently get as far as appending the uploaded chunk onto the file on the server, it's just the ffmpeg stuff I haven't the foggiest about

How would I go about doing this using `FFMPEG`?, or would it be just easier to wait for the full download?

I'm still in design phase so I haven't actually written anything yet, but this is a question purely about how to use ffmpeg to convert a partial file, stop, continue, ...., until the file has been converted completely

*This is apparently the same technique that YouTube uses when uploading a streamable file, which enables uploads to be performed quicker*

Comment: This seems to be a programming question, and as such off-topic. Even if it wasn't, you should include what you've tried and researched already, and where you are running into difficulty / what specific problems you have.

Comment: @bertieb it's a question about ffmpeg. The php side I can do easily, and I've updated to say that, but other ffmpeg posts I have read on here so I posted here

Comment: That's both an on-topic question, and a really interesting one!

Comment: @bertieb I've only used ffmpeg locally on my computer to convert videos from one format to another. However, it has to be on the most confusing CLI applications I've ever come accross with the host of available options, which is why I'm asking because no one else on Google seems to have an answer

Comment: FWIW I think it will end up being a programming question again (*"How do I do **X** with PHP"* definitely *was*!), as it may be easier to use the [`libav` interface programmatically](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Using%20libav*), as opposed to spawning instances of `ffmpeg`.

Comment: You can convert incomplete video files using ffmpeg using [pipes](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#pipe). I made [a simple single-file node conversion server](https://gist.github.com/qgustavor/c6d660525f31fcdd20e26b028c64a11e#file-convert-server-js-L55-L64) to show how to do it (conversion logic highlighted).